# Jquery delay,hide,remove are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to put animation effect while removing the div.

```
 onclick="$(this).parent().hide(1000).remove(1000);
```

hide is working there but not removing the html.

```
onclick="$(this).parent().hide(1000).remove();
```

now remove working but hide not working.after that i have put the delay method also.

```
$(this).parent().hide(1000).delay(1000).remove();
```

it should work but really don't know why its not working.

can anyone help me i don't want to use callback function.i just want to completely remove the div and its html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.hide` has a "complete" parameter to do exactly what you are asking for:

```
$(this).parent().hide(1000, function() { $(this).remove() });
```

When the `hide` animation has completed, it (the parent) will be removed.

If, for some unknown reason, you think this is a "callback" and don't want to do it, then you'll have to use setTimeout, but it's sucky:

```
$(this).parent().hide(1000);
setTimeout(function() { $(this).parent().remove(); }, 1000);
```

and "setTimeout" uses a "callback" parameter (depending on your definition of callback).

Comment: I've never used `hide` with a duration argument - try something more explicit such as `.fadeOut(1000)`.

Answer (score 3):

The `delay` function is only for animations. Please use `setTimeout()` instead:

```
onclick="$this = $(this); setTimeout(function () {$this.parent().hide().remove();}, 1000);"
```

Comment: @TariqHusain The above code executes after 1 second after clicking. What exactly you want it to happen.

Comment: it doesnt remove html nor hide the div.

Comment: @TariqHusain Can you please provide HTML?

Comment: @TariqHusain Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: $(this).parent().hide(1000,function(){$(this).remove()}) code worked for me

Comment: Updated the answer @TariqHusain. Sorry it was my mistake. Please check now.

Comment: Ah, okay, do you wanted an animation?

Comment: yea i was looking for any animation effect while removing html

Comment: @TariqHusain Try `fadeOut()`.